# ImproperlyConfigured at / Empty static prefix not permitted - Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-urls, static-files

I'm working on uploading/displaying images with Django.

The website is deployed on Heroku.

Following [this](https://coderwall.com/p/bz0sng) tutorial I was able to successfully upload images.

However, the images weren't being displayed in the template.

I then learned that my urls.py should have this line at the end:

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I added this to the end of my urls.py but now I'm getting this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at / Empty static prefix not permitted
```

I have MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in my settings.py and neither are empty.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Why is this error happening and how would I fix it?

Here's what I think is the relevant part of my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import notifications
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....urls......

) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: ...what is your `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`? You said they're defined; but what are they?

Comment: `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` is for development only, and only works with `debug` set to `True`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I added the same line in my urls.py and got the same error as you.

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/) says to use `settings.STATIC_URL` and `settings.STATIC_ROOT`

I changed it to the documentation version

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....urls......

) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and the error went away!

I checked my settings file and made sure `settings.MEDIA_URL` and `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` were both defined correctly. Later I adjusted urls.py back to using `settings.MEDIA_URL` and `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`. Everything worked as expected.

These are the relevant parts of my settings.py file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
REPOSITORY_ROOT = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(REPOSITORY_ROOT, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(REPOSITORY_ROOT, 'media/')
```

I think `MEDIA_URL` was set incorrectly

Comment: Thanks, Devin! For me, it was clearly the fault of the missing MEDIA_ROOT. url patterns can still be inside square brackets.

Answer (score 5):

You have too check both of the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT as well as for static files STATIC_ROOT STATIC_URL are defined correctly.

Check correct spelling also :)

If one of them is miss configured those will cause this error.

Answer (score 4):

To resolve the problem, the following statements must be added to the **settings.py** file:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for contributing. It would help others and the OP understanding your solution if you'd add more specific explanations (e.g. background information, what does it do, why does it help with the given problem).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that settings.py has:

```
# Media

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Then in the urls.py, try this

```
urlpatterns[
    ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you have this issue, ensure you have both MEDIA_URL AND MEDIA_ROOT set.

I was receiving the error

```
ImproperlyConfigured at / Empty static prefix not permitted
```

when I only had MEDIA_ROOT set in django 1.11

Alternatively, django project wiki says that it cannot refer to a URL in debug mode:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Answer (score 2):

I am following [Django 2.2 & Python | The Ultimate Web Development Bootcamp](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-ultimate-beginners-guide-to-django-django-2-python-web-dev-website/) my issue was that I have forgot to declare these to portfolio-project/portfolio/settings.py/ to the bottom area:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/Media/'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had recently got the same error when working with Django 2.1  The problem was I did not specify explicitly `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` in the project settings file.  Once I declared the same the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, I had to put `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` above the `STATICFILES_DIRS` declaration.

Answer (score -1):

Fix this error by adding this line in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 ....
]  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```